# Do I have to republish my whole DB project to apply a code change to the linked database?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a SQLServer project in Visual Studio, linked to a localDB instance - I can see the real state of the DB and the project script files and I have a publish script which lets me publish the project to the DB.

But doing this for every change is quite slow, yet this is the only way I know to sync my project and the the actual DB model. Is there a better way to keep the two in sync, even automatically? Many times I test changes only to realise my DB isn't up to date and lose time re-publishing and re-testing.

Irritatingly, when I look at the DB in SQL Server Explorer and do "show code" it shows me the *updated* version even when it is *not* applied.

Comment: Run a SQL Comparison (Right-click on Solution → `Schema Compare...`) between your Database Project and your Database - it gives you a checklist of objects that are different for you to pick-and-choose between, from that you can either generate a script from that to just apply the changes you want, or directly update it.

Comment: The database project uses LocalDB as well, on that starts with `Project...`. You have *two* LocalDBs. One that shows the project's data and another that you made yourself. You could say that SSDT already does what you ask.

Comment: @Siyual after a little searching I found this option and it's just what I wanted. Would you consider providing an answer based on your comment so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score -2):

To publish the database schema, right click on the database project > Publish. Verify the target database connection and click Publish. There is no need to generate the publish script at this point. Hope that helps.